# R Studio Exponential Distribution

Tags: r, statistics, quantile, exponential-distribution

I am trying to plot a quantile plot of an exponential distribution and I don't understand some part.

Here's what I enter into R

```
N=(1:10)
P=(N-0.5)/10
data=c(2,4,5,7,8,10,14,17,27,35)
m = mean(data)
expquantiles = qexp(P, 1/m)
plot(expquantiles,data)
```

However when I change the data to something else (see below) it says

```
    Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

The data I am using:

```
[1]   83  51  87  60  28  95   8  27  15  10  18  16  29  54  91   8  17  55  10
[20]  35  47  77  36  17  21  36  18  40  10   7  34  27  28  56   8  25  68 146
[39]  89  18  73  69   9  37  10  82  29   8  60  61  61  18 169  25   8  26  11
[58]  83  11  42  17  14   9  12
```

Comment: Can't see any `0.05`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @nicola Sorry I updated my question, I initially mixed the question up with something else

Comment: When you `plot` something, you need your `x` and `y` vectors to have the same length. Here, `expquantile` seems to have length of 10, while `data` is much longer.

Comment: @nicola I'm supposed to use the sample mean as the estimate of β. So what I did was N=(1:64) P=(N-0.5)/64 and plotted it and got a weird plot. I was wondering if this was the correct attempt for constructing a quantile plot to determine if the data comes from an exponential distribution?